# JavaScript / AngularJS modify property in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have the following AngularJS model:

```
$scope.Model = {
     Users : [{
         UserId: '',
         FirstName: '',
         LastName: ''
     }],
     Products :[{
         ProductId: '',
         Price: ''
     }]
};
```

If I populate this array with N users, and one user has `id=1`, how can I update that specific user (with `id=1`) the property `LastName`?

So for example if I will get a new AngularJS model:

```
$scope.UserToUpdate ={
   UserId: 1,
   LastName: "Smith"
};
```

I want to loop through the `$scope.Model` array and update the user with `id=1` but only the `FirstName` property.

P.S.  I don't know at what position the target user object in the array it is so basically can be at `$scope.Model.Users[0]` or `$scope.Model.Users[1]` or `$scope.Model.Users[10]` or at `$scope.Model.Users[N]` ...

Comment: your data structure is really strange, you have one object per array which is part of object in an array... hmmm

Comment: @harish: sorry made some mistakes in typing

Comment: $scope.model.Users will have one object or many objectS??

Comment: he said it will have N users, so many.

Comment: @harish: many objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just loop through your list of users

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.Model.Users.length; i++) {
    if($scope.Model.Users[i].UserId === $scope.UserToUpdate.UserId) {
        $scope.Model.Users[i].LastName = $scope.UserToUpdate.LastName;
        break;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Actually harish's answer is on to something too. Here's another solution using $filter:

```
var matchedUsers = $filter('filter')($scope.Model.Users, { UserId: $scope.UserToUpdate.UserId });
if (matchedUsers.length > 0) {
    matchedUsers[0].LastName = $scope.UserToUpdate.LastName;
}
```

And don't forget to add the $filter service as a parameter in your controller declaration for this second solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.UserToUpdate = 
   $scope.Model.Users.filter(function(user) { return user.FirstName == "test"; })[0];
```

BTW: you can add a check if the user exists..

Comment: Alright so that will basically will return the actual user object. How do I update it in place?

Comment: You have a reference to the "wanted" object. Now you can update it via javascript or add a template with ng-model to update it via inputs.

Answer (score 0):

you can use $filter

```
      var user = $filter('filter')($scope.Model.Users, 'UserId == 1');
```

you are read more about $filter('filter') [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

Answer (score 0):

Try this! working demo http://plnkr.co/edit/scyV79HqqA7nOG9h4ezH?p=preview . Please check the console log.

```
angular.forEach($scope.Model[0].Users, function(value1, key1) {
    var i = 0;
    angular.forEach(value1, function(value, key) {
      if (key == 'UserId' && $scope.UserToUpdate.UserId == value) {
        $scope.Model[0].Users[i].LastName = $scope.UserToUpdate.LastName;
      }
      i++;
    });

  });
```

The above code updating the `Model` object `LastName` property based on `UserToUpdate` object (id=1)